# css ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb can't change scale(gradient color)

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm trying to scale the thumb on the scrollbar and I can't change it's with and height also I wanna make it bigger than the scrollbar itself.

I have tried to add transparent borders to making the thumb smaller also adding a left border to show it outside the scrollbar. (first one for default mode and the second for :hover mode)
but it's not working

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;

    /*it's not helping with showing the thumb border-left*/
    overflow: auto;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 139, 0.7), rgba(0, 100, 0, 0.8));
    overflow: auto;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border-radius: 3px;

    /*doesnt work (the goal is making thumb thinner)*/
    border: transparent 5px solid;
    overflow: auto;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{

    /*doesnt work (the goal is make it bigger than scrollbar itself)*/
    transform: scale(1.5);
    border-left: 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) solid;
}
```

```html
<body style="height : 700px;">

</body>
```

[try it yourself here](https://jsfiddle.net/DivineAlien/83ef1cnq/23/)

I expect a scrollbar with gradient background-color and a smaller thumb that when is on hover (:hover) it will get bigger than scrollbar.
can you help me?

Comment: What's the idea about adding left border when hovering thumb ?

Comment: The main goal is to make some margin between thumb and scrollbar, then when hovering thumb it shoulb be 100% height and cover all scrollbar area .. right ?

Comment: I'm adding a left border to make thumb wider than scrollbar itself but it's not working.
nice help I will try with margin to make it work. thank you!

Comment: I'll post an an answer, I think  it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make thumb thinner use: `background-clip: padding-box` then add some padding to the thumb and this should work fine.

Then to make it wider when hovering remove `padding-box` by adding: `background-clip: initial;`

Note that There is no way to make thumb wider than scrollbar

Working Demo:

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 139, 0.7), rgba(0, 100, 0, 0.8));
  overflow: auto;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  overflow: auto;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: height 0.2s ease-in-out;
  padding: 5px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-clip: initial;
}
```